# Show banner only to certain country / IPs?

Tags: jquery, country

I'm adding a banner ads on my site.

This banner has to be visible only to Italian users (with Italian IP).

For now this code seems work:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            if(response.country == "IT") {
                alert("NOES!!!");
            }
        }, "jsonp");
    });
</script>
```

If IP is Italian, I see alert; if IP isn't Italian, I don't see it.

Now how can I add banner ads (banner is in script type) when user is Italian?

That's: if user is Italian then show banner

Code of the banner is of this type: `<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>`

Sorry for my English..

Thank you in advance

Comment: Is the script in a separate .js file?

Comment: I haven't a js file, only aff link as script src="http://aff.link/adv/text=numbercampain"

Answer (score 0):

You can create the `script` element and add it to the body:

```
var script = "<script></script>" //fill this with script needs
$("head").append(script);
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the script and execute it with an ajax call. Just put the JS code in a separate .js file.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});
```

Look at the jQuery site for more details http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

This way you only load the script if you need it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`$.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/) for that :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
        if(response.country == "IT") {
            $.getScript('http://domain.com/ads.js');
        }
    }, "jsonp");
});
```

Note that many ad networks, like AdSense etc. could ban you for stuff like this.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all replies, I have tried with your codes but don't work, because my affiliation link isn't type "http://domain.com/ads.js" but

script src="http://aff.link/adv/text=numbercampain"

I haven't .js file..